# Configuration of Perl script to generate XML sitemap automatically for a very huge website

Tags: xml, perl, web, seo, sitemap

I am a SEO working for a flight booking company. We are trying to get an XML sitemap installed for our site. I had asked the development team of my company to install a Perl script that will help to generate an XML sitemap for our huge site (more than 150k pages).

We used the [Google Perl Sitemap Generator](http://code.google.com/p/perlsitemapgenerator/wiki/Create) for the same, as for some reasons we can use only Perl. The output file had a lot of crap as it mainly crawled through the static pages and other content in the server folders (it basically did not follow the URLs from the homepage and down the site, but crawled every file on the server). I am not sure if the terminology is correct but I think you will get my point.

The configuration options are mentioned in the link above, however we are not able to figure out what parameters to use to obtain an ideal XML sitemap without the unnecessary URLs.

Could anyone please help with the Perl script or how to configure it.

Comment: Valid question indeed! Ive had trouble finding a sitemap generator myself!

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the site with 'wget' (mirror option) and build a sitemap from that.

Answer (score 0):

Look here, it has the code:
http://www.isrcomputing.com/knowledge-base/linux-tips/240-how-to-create-google-sitemap-
using-perl.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm naive, but couldn't you do a BFS 'http::get' of all links starting from the root, parsing out each `a href` ?

Perl supports that pretty well.